# Binding value from parent Page ViewModel to UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I write new WPF MVVM app.
I new in WPF.
I have problem with binding value to StageControl from MainPageModelView.
StageControl is in MainPage.
I know how binding value to element in MainPage, but I can't binding value to StageControl in this same way.
How can I binding value from MainPageModelView to StageControl?
Code:

MainPage.xaml

```
<my:StageControl x:Name="stageControl1" StageIsActive="true"  StageName="{Binding Stage.Name}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
...
<Label x:Name="lbTest" Content="{Binding Test}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="104,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="56" Width="68"/>
```

StageControl.xaml.cs

```
public partial class StageControl : UserControl
    {
        string stageName;
        bool stageIsActive;

        public StageControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool StageIsActive
        {
            get { return this.stageIsActive; }
            set { this.stageIsActive = SetStageControlStatus(value); }
        }

        public string StageName
        {
            get { return this.stageName; }
            set { this.stageName = SetStageName(value); }
        }

        private bool SetStageControlStatus(bool value)
        {
            if (value)
            {
                this.outRing.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.outRing.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                return false;
            }    
        }

        private string SetStageName(string value)
        {
            this.text.Text = value;
            return this.text.Text;
        }
    }
```

MainPageViewModel.cs

```
class MainPageViewModel
    {
        public List<Stage> Stages = new List<Stage>();
        public Stage stage = new Stage(0, "Test", true);

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            Stages = Stage.GetStages();
        }

        public string Test
        {
            get { return "Testowy Label"; }
            set { }
        }

    }
```

**Edit:**
MainPage.xaml.css

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPageViewModel viewModel = new MainPageViewModel();
            this.DataContext = viewModel;
        }
```

Comment: `StageName` has to be a dependency property

Comment: UserControl if used correctly will inherit the DataContext and will have access to the underlying data. Also `Page` doesn't inherit `DataContext`!!! Use ContentControl or ItemsControl with `DataTemplate` to preserve inheritance. View needs INotifyPropertyChanged implemented to pick up changes.

Comment: You can set binding only for dependency properties and StageName isn't.

Comment: I add dependency properties (public static readonly DependencyProperty StageNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("StageName", typeof(string), typeof(StageControl));) and now StageControl has text which i set as default/template in StageControl.xaml

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
First I add dependency property to StageControl.xaml.cs, then I add binding to StageControl.xaml

```
...
x:Name="Stage"
...
<TextBlock x:Name="text" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ElementName=Stage, Path=StageName}" TextAlignment="Center"  FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public Stage Stage {get;set;} = new Stage(0,"Test",true);
```

u need to make property instead of public variable